# Finding file extension of downloaded files (AIR)

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm trying to download Flickr videos using the Flickr API. The following URL downloads `3685555296_mobile.mp4`

http://www.flickr.com/photos/schill/3685555296/play/mobile/3ae21a2693/

Right now I'm using URLLoader (BINARY data format) to download and write the video to disk. Is there a way to find the extension of the video before writing it to disk? I need this to construct custom names for the video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in this [thread](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157621698855558/#comment72157621959129708). The file type info is sent in the "Content-Disposition" section of the MIME header.

So I figure by using the `contentType` property of the [URLRequest class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) you should be able to determine the file-type of the incoming file.

Comment: For both PROGRESS and COMPLETE event the urlrequest.contentType is null.

Comment: You could also try listening for [HTTPStatusEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html) on the `URLLoader`.

The event has a property `responseHeaders` which may contain the content-type.